# Склонение топонимов

Tags: грамотная-речь

В городе Перми или в городе Пермь?

Answer (score 1):

Правильно: **в городе Перми, как и в городе Москве.**

Названия  городов (тем более известных) склоняются при наличии родового слова, в отличие от названий аулов, деревень и др., для которых надо **сохранить точность названий**.

**Примечания:**

1) Склонение может отсутствовать в географической литературе.

2) Допускается отсутствие склонения для названий на ИНО/ЫНО и ОВО/ЕВО, где также важно сохранять начальную форму слова: в городе Пушкино, в городе Пушкин.